# как конвертировать базу ms sql в mysql

Tags: mysql, linux, sql-server

есть дамп бази даних ms sql файл some.bak 
как конвертировать дание с файла в mysql
в среде линукс

Comment: Полноценно никак. Хотя бы потому, что описание структуры таблици, не говоря о функциях и триггерах

Comment: никак. прямого способа не существует. надо каждую таблицу просмотреть в ручную, придумать соответствия типов данных одной БД к типам данных другой. после этого написать скрипт, который поменяет синтаксис оформления имен (как минимум заменит квадратные скобки на обратные апострофы). пошаманит с синтаксисом создания contraint, удалит из скрипта не поддерживаемые в MySQL возможности (или заменит их на что то). И да, исходный файл должен быть в формате sql-команд, а не двоичный дамп данных.

Answer (score 2):

Для задач миграции с MS SQL рекомендуют утилиту [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/).

Воспользуйтесь [инструкцией по миграции](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/migrate/) для изучения процесса перехода.

Comment: Смотрел но не смог найти способ конвертации с дампа, только напрямую с сервера
а мене надо с дампа сделать конвертацию

Comment: @vov4ok, у вас не дамп, а резервная копия. Из нее вы никак не конвертируете. Поднимайте сервер, восстанавливайте резервную копию и после этого мигрируйте.